# How to add EOF in a map

Tags: java

I'm reading this file:

```
ab ab cab
```

and counting the number of times each character appears and putting it in a map:

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
```

The resulting map looks like this:

```
{ =2, a=3, b=3, c=1 }
```

but I need the result to be this:

```
{ =2, a=3, b=3, c=1, EOF=1}
```

How do I add EOF=1 to the map? This is for an assignment and says I need that EOF=1.

Comment: You have code that handles the end of file, so you know when the file ends. Maybe an indication that you've read an `EOF` character?

Comment: I need to be able to put this EOF from a map into a priority queue and then into a binary tree. But I don't understand how to add it into the map

Answer (score 1):

EOF is not a character, so a `Map<Character, Integer>` can't use EOF as a key. So you'll need to adjust your approach.

Here are two options:

- You can choose some specific character that won't otherwise appear in your input (such as `'\0'` or `\uFFFF`), and use that character to represent EOF.
- You can use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` instead. Every character can be promoted to an integer (since integers range from −2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>−1, and characters only from 0 to 2<sup>16</sup>−1), so this lets you represent every character *and* EOF.
- You can store the count of EOF in a separate `int` variable.